# Two line ListView in Sherlock Activity

Tags: android, listview, actionbarsherlock

The app I'm developing is using ActionShercklockBar,

On the main activity (SherlockActivity) I have a bar with a search field,
A ListView (which is to have two entries per row)
and a spinner

the problem is that as I'm starting with android, all the tutorials I've found require that my activity extends from ListActivity

but mine is extending SherlockActivity so I'm a bit confused as to how I can implement the two lines entry

Could anyone point me to a resource on the web or provide some input on this?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to extend from ListActivity to use a ListView.  Just place a ListView in your layout and then set it's ListAdapter in your activity's onCreate method.  Here's an example that shows this style of ListView:  http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php

For the 2 line entry per row, you'll want to customize your List, so that you set the layout of each item displayed. Check out the OrderAdapter and the getView method implementation in this example: http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/

Comment: thanks Stan, about to have lunch and get into this after a bit, I'll mark the proper answer that helped me get going as right.

Comment: Stan, the second link was spot on! problem solved. Thanks you both for the input.

Comment: Now that I have it working, I need to find out how to make the first line in the row to be in the vertical center. The second one has a smaller font that should be just a tad below the first. I've been trying with android:gravity="center_vertical" to no avail. any clues?

Comment: Seems like a new question - if you post your layout code, I'm sure you'll get a working answer. Definitely depends on the layout type you are using (ex: LinearLayout or RelativeLayout). Having said that, I'll make a suggestion you've probably already tried: If you want to center left & right, instead of up & down, that's centering *horizontally*. If you do really want to center_vertical, and then have a small line underneath, that sounds like a job for a RelativeLayout, which has an attribute android:layout_centerInParent - setting that to true will center a view in the parent.

Comment: yes i made it a new question and ended up figuring it myself (the solution was indeed a RelativeLayout), it's here: http://goo.gl/0jSJd

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is to use the SherlockListActivity class and in adapter that you provided for your listView, in getView() method you have to create a custom view with two rows. There are a lots of tutorials on the web on how to create a custom item in your list view, so please have a look at that.

But if you will be still confused, write me and I will edit my answer with the real sample code.

Comment: thanks Martin, but as far I understand a ListActivity (or SherlockActivity) would make its ListView take the whole layout. no? (I', most likely wrong). The tuts I've seen also use a simple adapter with a HashMap but I can't use a HashMap (a there are repeated entries for a good reason, so the identical keys would overwrite the entry). The class I get the data from uses an ArrayList<Designation> where Designation is a custom class that, among other things, has String name, String orderedValue (these are the entries that are meant to into the two rows)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you, I have ActionShercklockBar and ListViews in the main activity.
What I did is to extend from SherlockListActivity in the main activity with a ListAdapter and it works well

Comment: could you elaborate a more how you did it?